# how to add hours and min in the text box in view to filter data

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller, view

i have two text boxes for from date and to date , i want to add two more text boxes for hrs:min, how to add two more text boxes and pass the values into my controlller so that i can filter the records according to the date as well as time.

view

```
 <span style="float:left; padding:10px;">Ftom Date : </span><input type="text" name="fromDate" value="@(ViewBag.FromDate != null ? Convert.ToDateTime(ViewBag.FromDate).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : "")" class="form-control datetime" id="txtFromDate" style="float:left; width:100px;" />
                <span style="float:left; padding:10px;">HRS : </span><input type="text" name="FromHrs" value="" class="form-control datetime" id="txtFromDate" style="float:left; width:50px;" placeholder="Hrs" /><input type="text" name="FromMin" value="" class="form-control datetime" id="txtFromDate" style="float:left; width:50px;" placeholder="Min" />

                <span style="float:left; padding:10px;">To Date : </span><input type="text" name="toDate" value="@(ViewBag.ToDate != null ? Convert.ToDateTime(ViewBag.ToDate).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : "")" class="form-control datetime" id="txtToDate" style="float:left; width:100px;" />
                <span style="float:left; padding:10px;">HRS : </span><input type="text" name="ToHrs" value="" class="form-control datetime" id="txtFromDate" style="float:left; width:50px;" placeholder="Hrs" /><input type="text" name="ToMin" value="" class="form-control datetime" id="txtFromDate" style="float:left; width:50px;" placeholder="Mins" />
                <span style="float:left; padding:10px;">Device : </span>
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "SignalTesting", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "form" }))
                {
                    <div>
                        <span >Ftom Date : </span><input type="text" name="fromDate" value="@(ViewBag.FromDate != null ? Convert.ToDateTime(ViewBag.FromDate).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : "")" class="form-control datetime" id="txtFromDate"  />
                    <span>To Date : </span><input type="text" name="toDate" value="@(ViewBag.ToDate != null ? Convert.ToDateTime(ViewBag.ToDate).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : "")" class="form-control datetime" id="txtToDate"  />
                        <span >Device : </span>
                        <select id="ddlDevices" name="DeviceID" class="form-control" >

                            ...
                         </select>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default"  />
                    </div>
                }
             </div>
        controller
       private AssetTracker getAssetDetails(string deviceID,int FHrs,int ToHrs,int FromMin,int ToMin, DateTime? fromDate = null, DateTime? toDate = null)

                {

                int Fromhours = FHrs;
                int Tohours = ToHrs;
                int From_min = FromMin;
                int To_min = ToMin;

           var items = Pirs.Where(a => !a.dataFrame.EndsWith("AAAAAAAAAAA=") && (fromDate == null || fromDate.Value.Date <= TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(Convert.ToDateTime(a.timestamp), TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time")).Date) && (toDate == null || toDate.Value.Date >= TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(Convert.ToDateTime(a.timestamp), TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time")).Date) && TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(Convert.ToDateTime(a.timestamp), TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time")).Hour >= Fromhours && TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(Convert.ToDateTime(a.timestamp), TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time")).Hour <= Tohours
                        && TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(Convert.ToDateTime(a.timestamp), TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time")).Minute >= From_min && TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(Convert.ToDateTime(a.timestamp), TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time")).Minute <= To_min) 
        }
```

Comment: Add 2 more inputs to the form and 2 more parameters to the action method. The parameter name should match with the new input element name

Comment: why not use fromDate to have both date  & time

Comment: date picker gives only date so im passing date only, dont now how to pass date with time in calender control

Comment: Use `<input type="time"  />`

Comment: im not getting proper records due to some mistake in my query im unable to filter by time ,as i taken from time and to time , i.e x > fromtime && x< totime. which is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you need.

Add the time input fields to your form:

```
<input type="text" id="fromTime" name="fromTime" />
<input type="text" id="toTime" name="toTime" />
```

Then update you controller to receive the new form values:

```
private AssetTracker getAssetDetails(string deviceID, DateTime? fromDate = null, DateTime? toDate = null, string fromTime, string toTime )
```